# Why can't Javascript spread operator be used after object key?

Tags: javascript, spread-syntax

I have the following code:

```
const array = [{
    a: 'a',
    b: 'b'
  }];

  console.log(...array);

  const store = {
    obj: ...array
  }
```

`console.log` will print the results just fine. However, when trying to set the key of `store` I get a `Parsing error: Unexpected token`.

Isn't `...array` a valid object to assign to the `obj` key of `store`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`...` spreads out array into individual items. Array can have more than 1 element and hence there will be more than 1 RHS and that will be invalid. Hence, you can use `obj : {...array}` or `obj : [...array]`

```js
const array = [{a: 'a',b: 'b'},{c: 'c', d: 'd'}];

console.log(...array);

const store = {
  obj: {...array},
  obj1: [...array]
};
  
  console.log(store);
```

Answer (score 1):

The spread syntax works inside of objects or iterable.  In your case, you need to spread the elements within an array.

> [Spread Syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax)
>
> Spread syntax allows an iterable such as an array expression or string to be ***expanded in places where zero or more arguments (for function calls) or elements (for array literals) are expected***, or an object expression to be expanded in places where zero or more key-value pairs (for object literals) are expected.

```js
const array = [0, 1, 2]
const store = {
  obj: [...array] // <-- the array is being spreded into an array.
}

console.log(store)
```